# Find which tiles are intersected between two points on an isometric tilemap

Tags: python, pygame, isometric

I need to be able to find out which tiles are intersected when a line is drawn between two points.

I'm currently working with a isometric perspective which makes things a little more complicated.

I've thought of simply checking every X pixels until target is reached by it would be very processing intensive.

I'm using Python and Pygame.

[image]

Comment: You should find the coordinates of the start and end points on the target plane, and then use a line rasterization algorithm, such as [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: No, doing this in isometric perspective is not more complicated, because the set of tiles crossed by a line in the world does not vary based on viewing perspective. [You solve this problem in your game simulation world space, which is not rotated, then project the result to your rotated isometric view](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/94149/39518).

Comment: Would a marching ant(bee) algorithm or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm be over complicated? The math is straightforward whereas the deprojection, calculate, reproject, seems much more complicated.